# How to create this JSON array with python?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

i need to create an array like this,

```
{
 "driver_details":[
       {
        "dr_id": 1,
        "v_id": 2,
        "v_type":"car",
        "condition":"ok"
       },
       {
        "dr_id": 2,
        "v_id": 3,
        "v_type":"cab",
        "condition":"ok"
       },
 ]
}
```

I tried with this method which returns `dr_id`, `v_id`, `condition`, `type` values as list,

But extracting values from it is difficult and cannot get specific data like `dr_id`,`v_id`.

```
def get(self, owId):

        return_data = []

        for driver in driver_schema.dump(DriverModel().get_driversby_ownerId(owId)):

            for vehicle in vehicle_schema.dump(VehicleModel().vehicle_detailby_driver(driver['dr_id'])):
                return_data.append(driver['dr_id'])
                return_data.append(vehicle['vehicle_type'])
                return_data.append(vehicle['condition'])

        return return_data
```

So I tried with `json.dump()` method but it returns the following value

`"[1.0, \"car\", false, 13.0, false, 2.0, \"bus\", false, 50.0, false]"`

and also i tried with dictionary inside the loop like following

```
def get(self, owId):

        return_data = {}

        for driver in driver_schema.dump(DriverModel().get_driversby_ownerId(owId)):

            for vehicle in vehicle_schema.dump(VehicleModel().vehicle_detailby_driver(driver['dr_id'])):
                return_data.update({'driver':driver['dr_id'], 'vehicle':vehicle['vehicle_type'], 'v_type':vehicle['vehicle_type']})

        return return_data
```

in this way, it only contains the last value from the loop.

So how can I achieve my expected results?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to see only the last value because you are modifying on the same dictionary (update) again and again . Instead you can add those dictionary values to the list .

```
def get(self, owId):

        return_data = []

        for driver in driver_schema.dump(DriverModel().get_driversby_ownerId(owId)):

            for vehicle in vehicle_schema.dump(VehicleModel().vehicle_detailby_driver(driver['dr_id'])):
                return_data.append({'driver':driver['dr_id'], 'vehicle':vehicle['vehicle_type'], 'v_type':vehicle['vehicle_type']})

        return return_data
```

After that you will be able to create a json with json.dumps().

Comment: `json.dumps()` or `json.load()` ?

Comment: Yeah , its json.dumps() .

Answer (score 2):

Prepare a list of all driver and then map it with `driver_details` key in dict and return that dict.

```
def get(self, owId):

    driver_details = []

    for driver in driver_schema.dump(DriverModel().get_driversby_ownerId(owId)):

        for vehicle in vehicle_schema.dump(VehicleModel().vehicle_detailby_driver(driver['dr_id'])):
            driver_details.append({
                 'driver': driver['dr_id'], 
                 'vehicle': vehicle['vehicle_type'], 
                 'v_type': vehicle['vehicle_type']
            })

    return {'driver_details': driver_details}
```